# Sci-fi novel (c2000±10) of time differential universes

Tags: story-identification, novel

Trans-solar human society, consciousness download to mini-bots fighting bugs, a scientist & an autist in an asteroid (Ceres?), and alien invasion foiled by travel to a time differential universe.  That sums up the novel in a TL;DR nutshell.

The question is: ***What is the title of this book?***

The expanded details (containing spoilers) are as follow:

- I read the book c2010 (absolutely definitely before 2015), which limits the publishing date; if it helps at all, it wasn't particularly pulp sci-fi (which I love), but clearly not hard SF, just general sci-fi (with a classically pulp twist to save the day) of typical sci-fi style (not YA or anything, and I believe that all of the characters were adults, no kids or 'teens, nor any special mention of animals), written in English, and was a paperback of perhaps 180-220 pages.  I believe that at that time the book had then been either new (that year) or no more than a few years old (say 5, maybe 10?); it definitely wasn't golden age or silver age, and I'm almost certain that it wasn't even as old as the '80s or '90s.  I don't remember thinking that the author was remarkably good or bad as a story-crafter or word-smith; since these generally grab my attention, I'm assuming that they were approximately average at these.  It was decently told as a tale, but with only a general sense of someone else's impending doom in some far off place and a few more-character-specific gripping scenes (e.g.: an ST:TOS novel), not a gripping and intense grimdark atmosphere (as with *Warhammer 40K*), nor the half-philosophical observations of “*Starship Troopers*” (much less the OTT satirical atmosphere of “*Bill the Galactic Hero*”).  While the ending left room for a sequel in principle, none seemed implied, nor do I remember a splash blurb to such an effect.
- I think that human society hadn't expanded beyond the solar system, but I can't be absolutely certain (if they had, then it certainly wasn't very far — maybe a local star or two, but very definitely not particularly widespread, much less trans- or inter-galactic).  The main plot takes place across this society, rather than being focused on any specific planet or satellite (natural or artificial) or ship, though I believe that Earth and at least one or two Jovians (or moons) were named for some of the plot arc settings, and definitely at least one asteroid in particular (I think Ceres, but I could be wrong).
- The transferred-consciousness-controlled robotic bodies fought [living] bugs using live rounds in an FPS game, basically.  I think that they were termites, but there could have been ants or a scorpion involved at some point (or made mention of in context of other battles in the character's memory).  The gaming 'bot-bodies bore [miniature] modern weapons or perhaps a little better, but definitely weren't stuck with ancient or medieval weaponry and armor.  This bit was told from one of the character's perspective (not necessarily 1POV, but at least with a narrative voice along that vein).  There was a short but intense battle; the character's 'bot-body got destroyed (crushed, pierced, smashed, or acid burned) by a bug; the character awoke from the game in a chair or reclining pod, and waited for the others (who were still in the game) to finish, and there was a little discussion between the gamers about the in-game death.
- Somewhere in the middle of all of this (probably no later than the middle or end of the first act, and possibly even before the start of the story), it was discovered that one could drop from our universe into others (I don't remember the handwave mechanism for this), and the deeper that one went, the greater the time flow differential.  At some point (probably the second or third act), some of the characters traveled to one such universe with an aquatic world (unless the air itself were thick), getting stranded somehow (the local aliens might have been militaristic, though a bit primitive).  Somewhat later (I think that they were on the run by this point), this team dived deep to a universe with physical laws that drove stars to be nebulous (this I remember firmly, if not clearly: they were blurry stars, smeared-out a bit, and possibly not very luminous; I don't remember if they were pastel colored or if that's just my own thought); there were some jellyfish-like creatures (maybe they were the pastel that I'm thinking of) in that universe that they figured were unlikely to ever evolve higher intelligence, and this somehow had to do with the local physics (I think the atmosphere just sort of generally extended outward without a Kármán line as such, though I could be mistaken).
- Between the end of the second act and the middle of the third, a fairly main character scientist (female, I think) who'd been working on something (possibly smart matter) succeeded at some aspect of this (though the aspect in question might not have been their direct goal), with the upshot (intentional or not) of helping the autist in some breakthrough fashion.  This occurred in the asteroid (used as a research station), but I believe that they had gone there as a fallback position (having begun their roles in the story at some other location).
- The character who saved the day did so by lying to the aliens, telling them of some supposed secret human stronghold or research base deep down the time-differential stack of universes — at the very bottom of them, in fact, in the last universe of the stack (I think that it was called the aleph level).  This universe that the aliens traveled to (with the hero in tow, though they'd likely kill him when they discovered his ruse) had a gamma factor of at least 10e3 or e4, and probably more like 10e7+.  The hero had sent the good guys a farewell message, telling them that while he expected the aliens to return soon from their own perspective (perhaps 20 minutes, perhaps a few weeks, pretty sure that it wasn't anything as long as 6 months), the human defenders should have plenty of time to advance their technology sufficiently in the meantime (perhaps 1,000-2,000 years from their universe's normal-time perspective).

I've Googled this on and off for about 3 years now, to no avail (obviously), and have finally decided to simply ask (so you now know that at least you won't run into this question anywhere else, or at least none by me as far as I can recall).  It's not actually important that I find the answer, but it's been nagging me.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Very nice and detailed question.  Do you recall anything about the cover art?  (I'm assuming this was an actual book; if it's an e-book it would be good to note that too.)

Comment: @DavidW No need to assume: it was a paperback. That said though, no. I checked the recommendations for formulating questions specific to this SE, and saw the suggestion re. cover art, but don't recall it for this novel (I often do, but I drew a blank on this one).  If I may ask, why delete the "Soft sci-fi" tag?

Comment: [tag:soft-sci-fi] isn't really a very good tag; what is "soft" is very subjective and, the way the tag help is written, it applies to 2 different things.  Plus, from your description the actual physics of the universes at various depths plays a role in the story, which implies more thought and attention paid to the science of the story than would fit with what is normally considered "soft."

Comment: Fair reasoning. I fear that I come from a math and physics geek perspective, where Cramer or Forward (et al.) are hard, and other stuff is... less so.  My bad.  

Comment: Not at all; cleaning up little things like that is what review is _for_. :)  "Soft" is for stuff like *The Stainless Steel Rat*, or the *Barsoom* novels.

Comment: You've mentioned a few terms that seem like they would be extremely helpful in searching, but you've not put them in quotes. Are they directly from the novel or your own words (e.g. "Gamma Factor", "10e3", "10e7+", "stack of universes"), etc.

Comment: @Valorum Unfortunately none are quoted pieces from the book.  Gamma factor is a physics term, the measure of Lorentz dilation (basically how warped the physical distance or [in this case] relative time scale); 10e3/etc. is scientific notation to shorthand long numbers (e.g.: 10e3 = 1,000); stack of universes is just my own evocative wording to describe the sequential nature of how this novel portrayed there being one universe after another as one went deeper along the handwaved dimension (physics again: "dimension of freedom", not the comics term for "universe").

Comment: @DavidW - I think we should withdraw the tag entirely. It's misused more than it's used.